# How to get options to show one after the other

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's show and delay to get 3 buttons to show one after the other, however I feel I may be trying to attack this from the wrong angle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
        $("#menu").show().delay(1000);
        $("#option1").show().delay(500);
        $("#option2").show().delay(500);
        $("#option3").show().delay(500);
    });
});
```

Is what I have right now.

So what I want to happen is when the user presses the button with the id "menu-button" the div with the id "menu" will show, and then each option will show one after the other.

However, what is happening is when I press the menu-button the menu and options all show at once.

I haven't really used jQuery much, so I am probably doing something wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I also tried, what I though the documentation was hinting at doing, which didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
        $("#menu").delay(1000).show();
        $("#option1").delay(1500).show();
        $("#option2").delay(2000).show();
        $("#option3").delay(2500).show();
    });
});
```

EDIT:

```
<body>
<span id="menu-button">TEST</span>
<div class="mobMenu hidden" id="menu">
<button class="hidden" id="option1">1</button>
<button class="hidden" id="option2">2</button>
<button class="hidden" id="option3">3</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at using done() to chain your revealing.  http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/  What this will do is wait for the animation to finish before calling the done callback to continue.

Comment: Could you add your HTML to the question.

Comment: Added HTML, left it out as I didn't think it was needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can pass a function that will be called after show function finishes:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
        $("#menu").show(1000, function() {
            $("#option1").show(1500, function() {
                 //And so on.
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: It's a little less clean, in my opinion, but I can't say it doesn't work :)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

this might be an easier way to accomplish the same task

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delay = 1000;
    var items = [
        '#menu', '#option1', '#option2', '#option3'
    ];

    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
        $.each(items, function(index, item){
            $(item).show().delay(delay);
            delay += 500;
        });
    });
});
```